# Problema con Gulp Build

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, gulp

En mi proyecto estoy usando Gulp. Tengo dos problemas:

1. No copia las imágenes a la carpeta `dist`. Estoy usando `imagemin`. Ya chequeé múltiples veces el directorio, pero no veo el error. Mis carpetas están organizadas de la siguiente manera:

   `|- app/
         |- css/
         |- fonts/
         |- images/ 
         |- index.html
         |- js/ 
              |- jQuery Nice Select/
              |- jQuery Validation/
         |- scss/
     |- dist/
     |- gulpfile.js
     |- node_modules/
     |- package.json`
2. Estoy usando el plugin *Nice Select* y *jQuery Validate* y parece no incluirlos en el build, ya que al ver la página en producción, el `select`aparece como el default del explorador y las validaciones no funcionan.

**HTML**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--build:js js/main.min.js -->
    <script src="js/simulador.js"></script>         
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

    <script src="js/lib/jquery-validation-1.16.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery-nice-select/jquery.nice-select.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var gulpIf = require('gulp-if');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var cache = require('gulp-cache');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
var del = require('del');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');


gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass()) // Using gulp-sass
      .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
      .pipe(browserSync.reload({
        stream: true
    }))
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
        baseDir: 'app'
        },
    })
});

gulp.task('useref', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});

gulp.task('images', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({
        interlaced: true
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
});

gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))
});

gulp.task('clean:dist', function() {
    return del.sync('dist');
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function(){
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']); 
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload); 
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload); 
});

gulp.task('build', function (callback) {
    runSequence('clean:dist', 
      ['sass', 'useref', 'images', 'fonts'],
      callback
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

1) Tema imágenes:

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)')
        .pipe(imagemin(cache({
            interlaced: true
        })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
});
```

La solución radica en poner `cache` luego de `imagemin`. De la forma inversa no lo tomaba.

2) Tema plugins:
De alguna extraña manera `cssnano` interfería con el minificado de los `js`. Cambié a `cleanCSS` y ahora todo funciona perfecto.